# Relaciones de Base Mysql -

Tags: mysql, eloquent, orm

Estoy un poco confundido con estás relaciones.

Estoy haciendo un juego de preguntas y respuestas.

En un grupo | Tabla | un usuario hace una publicación con una serie de preguntas.((de echo ese usuario  que hace preguntas solo puede hacerlas quien hizo dicho grupo))

Las cuales otros usuarios del mismo grupo puede responder dichas preguntas.

pero tengo duda respecto a las relaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como dije en la tabla usuarios dichos usuarios se pueden inscribir a un grupo. el cual ese grupo fue creado por un usuario X. Bien entonces, ese que creo dicho grupo, hace preguntas. Pero solo Los  que estan inscritos a dicho grupo pueden responderlas.

Entonces, ¿Cómo relaciono respuestas?

se que tiene que ir respuestas con usuario, Y pareciera un CICLO.Pero entonces¿?.Que hago¿?.

y Respuestas  tiene que ir con preguntas no?

--

de hecho un usuario se puede inscribir a otro grupo, sin importar que el ya haya creado otros grupos.

Comment: A simple vista faltaría una tabla `grupos_suscritos` donde se exprese qué usuarios están suscritos a qué grupos. Haciendo eso creo que encontrarás el camino natural para  saber enlazar `respuestas`, que sería: relacionar `usuarios` con `grupos_suscritos` -> `grupos` -> `publicaciones` -> `respuestas`. Hay otra cosa que no queda clara. ¿Las respuestas son fijas, tipo selección múltiple?  Si es sí, habría que incorporar otra tabla `usuarios_respuestas` y eso cambiaría varias cosas.

Comment: las respuestas no son con opcion multiple @A.Cedano son un tanto abiertas, donde esta grupo_usuario. Es el pivot que hace que se note los usuarios que estan suscritos a un grupo.